# Creating address locator for data with no ZIP codes?

Tags: address, zip-codes, geocoding

I am trying to create an address locator using Tiger/line data (dual address locator). While initially successful, I can only geocode addresses that have ZIP codes in the dataset. Most of the data I work with,however, does not contain ZIP code information, only street address.

How can I this problem?